# bottom: 0 doesn't work in Firefox with fixed positioning

Tags: css, firefox

I have a [simple page](https://write.as/pad) with a `textarea` that I want to fill the entire screen, except for a bit at the top. It works perfectly in Chrome but doesn't stretch to the bottom of the window in Firefox. This is the CSS I'm using:

```
body#pad textarea {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  padding: 1em 2em 2em;
  resize: none;
}
```

When I add `height: 100%` it does reach 100% in height, but that's not what I want, since it needs a little space at the top of the screen. Is there any *pure CSS* way to fix this? I'd really like to make it look and function like it does in Chrome without any Javascript.

Comment: Updated my answer with a better explanation and a 2:nd sample that might can come in handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As* [***MDN***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom)

> When both `top` and `bottom` are specified, and `height` is unspecified or
>   either `auto` or `100%`, both the `top` and `bottom` distances are respected.
>   In all other situations, if `height` is constrained in any way, ***the `top`
>   property takes precedence and the `bottom` property is ignored.***

So I suggest this trick to do, just remove `top: 3em;` and add `height:calc(100% - 3em);`

```css
textarea {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 3em);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  padding: 1em 2em 2em;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="write..."></textarea>
```

Comment: I was able to leave `top: 3em` in, and added `height: auto` before `height: calc(...)` as a fallback, but the idea worked. Thanks! 

Of course I'm still not sure how `height` is constrained in my case, or which behavior is the "correct" one (seems like Chrome's would be). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: FWIW, The HTML5 spec says that for textarea elements: ["Visual user agents should set the height of the control to the number of lines given by character height."](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#ref-for-character-height-1) where the character height is taken from the rows attribute of the textarea, and which takes a default value when not explicitly specified. That's what Firefox is doing. So the height is constrained. But note that it's a "should", not a "must", so Chrome's behaviour is  allowed too.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Don't know why FF misbehave so here is a workaround using [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)</strike>

Firefox appear to follow [this rendering rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-textarea-element-0) and by doing so actually have a preset height (and width) for the `textarea` element. It is this preset that overrides the `top`-`bottom`/`left`-`right` settings and therefore become constrained causing the constraint rules ([`top`-`bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) / [`left`-`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right)) to apply.

To make all browsers behave the same, a height and width need to be set explicit, where I used [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to get the correct height.

*(the right and bottom properties can be removed as they no longer affect the rendered result)*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
textarea {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 3em);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
write more...
</textarea>
```

In some situations the `top`-`bottom`/`left`-`right` properties is needed when using positioning, so for a `textarea`, one can use a wrapper like this

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
textarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea>
    write more...
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this css seem to work [https://jsfiddle.net/ubc4nz9k/]https://jsfiddle.net/ubc4nz9k/  set padding-top to your needs

```
#pad textarea {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
box-sizing: border-box;

background-color: #222;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.2em;
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
padding: 1em 2em 2em;
resize: none;
}

#pad { 
padding-top: 20px;
position: fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```