# padding-bottom doesn't work for fixed positioned div in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-position, overflow, padding

Here's the simple code to reproduce:

```css
#container {
  border: 5px dashed green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 3em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#child {
  height: 1000px;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

#### Expected behavior

[image]

Chrome works this way.

#### Actual behavior in Firefox

[image]

Am I missing something about CSS or this is a bug in Firefox?

Comment: yes a known bug since too long: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29986977/8620333

Comment: there is other related question, will try to find them and update the duplicate list

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```css
#container {
  border: 5px dashed green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#child {
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 3em;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question I've asked :)

Comment: I can understand , actually padding bottom is working fine its this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803803/bottom-0-doesnt-work-in-firefox-with-fixed-positioning